# Create promQL query to compare versions deployed across regions

Tags: promql

The services exposes their git hash to micrometer which reads something like

```
PACKAGE_VERSION_total{revision="b6d9de0"}, 0
```

(It's a counter, but I'm just using the label to show the version and don't need the counter value).

There is also another label called 'region' which will equate to something like `eu-west-2`.

The query will be used in alerting, and will need to return if **one of the services has a different version running** (obviously this will need to be relaxed during deployments, but the alerts tool has this functionality built in).

Is it possible to compare the revision label across regions to find a difference of more than 1?

Something like (I know this is wrong)

```
sum by (revision) (PACKAGE_VERSION_total) by (region) > 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "'region' metric"? If it is standalone metric, than how it can be connected to `PACKAGE_VERSION_total`? Or is it a label in `PACKAGE_VERSION_total`?

Comment: It's a stand alone metric. I want to compare revision across regions and find if there is a different of more than 1

Comment: So you want all version within region to be the same? Or all versions all over the globe to be the same?

Comment: And does this metric applies to a single service, or it is expected to separate versions of different versions in some way?

Comment: Looking for all versions across the globe to be the same. PS. there should only be one deployment per region.

Comment: Then you don't need to care about regions at all. You can simply use `count(count by (revision) (PACKAGE_VERSION_total)) > 1`